# Angular 9 pass method from component to a service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I have some websocket code where I send a message to the websocket server and I get the reply.

This code works fine but I want to put it inside a service and then just call it from the component.

Here is the code which right now is inside the component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {webSocket, WebSocketSubject} from 'rxjs/webSocket';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  myWebSocket: WebSocketSubject<any> = webSocket('ws://localhost:8888');

  constructor() {

    this.myWebSocket.subscribe(
      msg => console.log('message received: ' + msg),
      err => console.log(err),
      () => console.log('complete')
   );

  }

  sendMessageToServer(msg) {
    const dte = Date.now();
    this.myWebSocket.next({message: `${msg} - ${dte}` });
  }

}
```

I have now created a service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WsService {

  constructor() { }
}
```

How do I do this...which parts go from the component to the service...For example do I subscribe inside the service or in the component?

Comment: Please, be more precise. What is your goal? Where is this supposed to end? What is your application for?

Comment: My goad is to have the functionality in the service so I just call the service the normal way and keep the component as clean as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joe, the idea when you has a service is that the "subscribe" was IN component. Well, you can traslade to the service all else subscription

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WsService {
  myWebSocket: WebSocketSubject<any> = webSocket('ws://localhost:8888');

  constructor() {
  }

  sendMessageToServer(msg) {
    const dte = Date.now();
    this.myWebSocket.next({message: `${msg} - ${dte}` });
  }
}
```

And in component subscribe to ws.myWebSocket (I like subscribe in ngOnInit)

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private ws:WsService ) {

  ngOnInit()
  {
     this.ws.myWebSocket.subscribe(
      msg => console.log('message received: ' + msg),
      err => console.log(err),
      () => console.log('complete')
   );
  }
  addMessage(msg)
  {
   this.ws.sendMessageToServer(msg)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bring the service into your component. Steps:
Import your service into component.

```
import { WsService} from 'path/to/WsService';
```

Introduce local field `private wsService: WsService;`
Add your service into components constructor:

```
constructor(wsService: WsService)
{
    this.wsService = wsService;
}
```

Use your service like: `this.wsService.Method()`

Comment: I understand that but does this go in the component of in the service? this.myWebSocket.subscribe(
      msg => console.log('message received: ' + msg),
      err => console.log(err),
      () => console.log('complete')
   );

Comment: It depends. When there is no other component using this subscription, you can leave it inside the component. If more than one component or service needs access to it, then move it into a service. This is what services are made for.

Comment: There WILL be several components using the service

Comment: Then you have your answer. ;o)  In this case you have to move it into the service.